# How to evaluate the perforamance of clustering model using python

Tags: clustering, python, scikit-learn, k-means, model-evaluation

I have implemented the k means clustering model using python , i would like  to know whether my model is perfect or not , so that i want to know which performance metrics is used for clustering model to evaluate the clustering model .please suggest on this .
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

MSE is typically used. Notice how it looks like average euclidean distance between each point and the cluster center. Subscript i refers to the mean of each cluster.

[image]

[There are also other methods](https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-measure-error-in-a-K-means-clustering-algorithm), but MSE is most common. It depends what you are doing.